# Weird error related to stoi?

Tags: c++

I am trying to convert a string into an int by using stoi, but for some reason it is giving me an error and giving me this message:

"libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::invalid_argument: stoi: no conversion"

The line that deals with stoi is bolded, toward the bottom of the code.

Here is my code:

```
 #include "LongDistanceCalls.h"
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <sstream>
 #include <algorithm>
 #include <iterator>

using namespace std;  


string line;
string temp = "";
string beginning_time;

void convertTimeintoInt(string beginning_time)
{
  for(char a : beginning_time)
  {
     if(a == ':')
            continue;
    else
       temp += a;
  }
}

int main()
{
  ifstream inFile;
  string day;
  int minutes;
  double total_callpay;
  //opens .txt file
  inFile.open("CallRecords.txt");

  //if .txt file is openable, printed to command line.
  if (inFile.is_open())
  {
     cout<<"Day Time Duration Cost"<<endl;

     while(getline(inFile,line))
     {
         istringstream split(line);//splits each string into 3 seperate strings (day, beginning_time, minutes)

        while(split)
             {
               split >> day;
               split >> beginning_time;
               split >> minutes;
               **int time = stoi(temp);**
               time = time > 0 && time < 2400;
```

Comment: `temp` is just an empty string, you don't seem to be setting it anywhere else in the program.

Comment: From the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol): Exceptions
std::invalid_argument if no conversion could be performed
std::out_of_range if the converted value would fall out of the range of the result type or if the underlying function (std::strtol or std::strtoll) sets errno to ERANGE.

Comment: Your global variable `temp` is not updated anywhere in `main` or by any function called in `main`. Using a debugger would let you see what value was in `temp` at the time of the crash.

Comment: Can you post your `#include` statements?

Comment: @JoelTrauger You must be new here. His question contains the answer to his question if he'd bother to read and understand the exception message he posted. He's passing an invalid empty string to `stoi()`. If he'd try using a debugger, he'd know that.

Comment: Did you try printing out the contents of the string before trying to convert it to an integer?

Comment: @JoelTrauger I have posted the #include statements.  And what would I have to pass through stoi? I tried passing string beginning_time but it gives me an error.

Comment: @RobK We were all n00bs once. There is no such thing as a dumb question. However ridiculous the question may be, someone is asking it because they simply cannot see the answer to it. Heck, today I tried to send an email with code and couldn't understand why it wasn't sending. I left out the `email.send(message);` code. So give him a break and answer his question or move on.

Comment: @juanchopanza This is true, hence the answer I posted. I showed where he modified the variable, showed where he accessed it, and then posted a link to the cplusplus website showing how his code is causing the error. Nowhere have I actually posted a solution because that is his to come up with. I just don't see how his question warrants this many negative votes.

Comment: @JoelTrauger It shows no research effort and is cluttered with irrelevant code. See [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

`string temp = "";`

```
int main()
{
    ...
    int time = stoi(temp);
    ...
}
```

Where do you change the value of temp. `stoi` is erroring out because the input value is an empty string. [See here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/?kw=stoi#exceptions) under the Exceptions entry at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

First in this code:

```
string beginning_time;

void convertTimeintoInt(string beginning_time)
{
   for(char a : beginning_time)
   {
      if(a == ':')
           continue;
      else
           temp += a;
   }
}
```

you have global variable `beginning_time` as well as argument with the same name. So inside function you use local variable, not global one. This is one of the reason it is recommended to avoid global vars as much as possible.

Second you only define function `convertTimeintoInt` but you do not actually call it, so it does nothing. Instead you should avoid using global vars and make your function like this:

```
int convertTimeintoInt( string beginning_time )
{
    string temp;
    for(char a : beginning_time)
    {
        if(a == ':')
            continue;
        else
            temp += a;
    }
    return std::stoi( temp );
}
```

and then call it inside `main()`:

```
    split >> beginning_time;
    split >> minutes;
    int time = convertTimeintoInt( beginning_time );
```

Note: I did just copy your function implementation assuming it has correct behavior for you.